# Understanding concurrent Locust users

Tags: python, performance-testing, load-testing, traffic, locust

Assume i have a server running in my local machine at port 8081. Now i want to perform a load test for it using locust. I have few doubts regarding few command line arguments.

1. -u , --users which means the number of cconcurrent users the locust is going to generate.
   Now lets assume my machine only takes 20 ms to handle one request. I have 2 gunicorn workers running , which means i can handle 2 concurrent request at a time.If the 2 request sent by locust gets finished in 20 ms , does that mean the gunicorn workers will be idle because the locust will only be sending 2 concurrent request for a second or the locust will be sending another set of 2 concurrent request once locust gets the response back from the server(will not wait for that second to get completed. SO is it like at any given point of time there will be 2 concurrent request being handled by the server).
2. Is there any relationship between --users and --spawn-rate command line argument ?
3. i also assume that the -u means , that the locust will have n concurrent clients that will be sending request.

please correct me if i have gone wrong anywhere.
Thanks in Advance!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

You must have figured it out by now.

At the current time of writing this answer locust is on version 2.2.3. See docs: https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/configuration.html#all-available-configuration-options

- The specified **--users** is the **maximum** number of users created (see your User class) at any given time. Each user will try to send all the request it is given in the Task list until it dies.
- The **--spawn-rate** is the number of user created per second.